# Tensorflow: Custom loss function leads to op outside of function building code error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I'm using Tensorflow to write a NN-model to approximate the sine function and I'd like to use the second derivative w.r.t. to the input in the loss-function for my model.

My code doesn't yet include the derivative, but I just added the input tensor in my loss function (as first step) and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464549/keras-custom-loss-function-accessing-current-input-pattern?rq=1) answer as an first approach.

My code currently looks like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras
from numpy import random

# --- Settings
x_min = 0
x_max = 2*np.pi

n_train = 64
n_test = 64

# --- Generate dataset
x_train = random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n_train)
y_train = np.sin(x_train)

x_test = random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n_test)
y_test = np.sin(x_test)

# --- Create model
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh", input_dim=1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh"))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh"))

def custom_loss_wrapper(input_tensor):

    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) + keras.backend.mean(input_tensor)

    return custom_loss

# --- Configure learning process
model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
        loss=custom_loss_wrapper(model.input),
        metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])

# --- Train from dataset
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

My custom loss function just computes the mean-squared-error and adds the input value. This shouldn't be a problem, but I receive the error

> ```
> TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
> a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
> leak out of the function building context by including a
> tf.init_scope in your function building code.
> For example, the following function will fail:
>   @tf.function
>   def has_init_scope():
>     my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
>     with tf.init_scope():
>       added = my_constant * 2
> The graph tensor has name: dense_input:0
> ```

Does anybody know why this occurs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66966915/10375049

Answer (score 2):

Since TensorFlow 2.0 and higher is running on the eager mode by default,
Tensorflow op will check if the inputs are of type ***"tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor"*** and since Keras is implemented,
the inputs to the eager mode will be of **"tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor"** and this throws the error

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
```

You can change the input type to EagerTensor by explicitly telling TensorFlow to run in eager mode for Keras.
Setting this to true will solve the issue

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

Comment: OK but is it possible to pass a "tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor" to "custom_loss_wrapper" without being in eager mode and lose performance? I need a keras.Input to be passed to my loss function. It is similar to this issue here and I wish to avoid concatenation approaches.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704771/inputs-to-eager-execution-function-cannot-be-keras-symbolic-tensors